# Paste Special VBA does not work in embedded excel workbook

Tags: vba, excel, visio

I'm having an issue with the PasteSpecial function when working in an embedded excel workbook. The program I am working in is "Promax" which is block diagramming software running in Visio, which has the option to add an embedded excel workbook. I've essentially set up a number of cells in excel so that I can import a bunch of fields into a PDF form.

While working in the embedded workbook I am unable to get this function to give any output into the new excel worksheet. If I save a version of the workbook that is outside of promax, the code runs fine. If I just try to paste instead of paste special the code works fine, but all of the references that I pasted break in the new workbook.

```
Sub ExporttotxtFile()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim saveFile As String
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set WorkRng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:HK2")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add
WorkRng.Copy
wb.Worksheets(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
saveFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="Export", fileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
wb.SaveAs Filename:=saveFile, FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
wb.Close
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Does anyone have a solution to this or another method of getting this done? This code was taken from this: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/612-excel-export-data-to-text.html

Thanks!

Comment: what happens if you enable _ScreenUpdating_  and _DisplayAlerts_ ?  ... you could eliminate one _PasteSpecial_ line if you use `wb.Worksheets(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats`

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: also, please do not use `.Select  .... Selection.` form in your code if you can help it. use the format that you used in the first _PasteSpecial_ line.  reason: `Selection` refers to any cell or range of that you happen to click on or select even while the program is running. think of what would happen if you are doing a long calculation and you happen to click the mouse or touch the touchscreen(if you happen to have a touchscreen).

Answer (score 0):

While playing around with this more it seemed like xlPasteFormat was pasting an image over the values rather than formatting. I scrapped the pastespecial method and used a different solution.

```
    wb.Worksheets(1).Paste
    wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:HK2").Value = WorkRng.Value
```

I paste everything with the first paste and set the values with the second line so that the formatting stays.

Thanks for the help everyone.